# There is a permission denied error when I share repo between pycharm and github

Tags: github, version-control, pycharm

Git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

I am facing this problem while cloning repository from my GitHub account to PyCharm.
I have logged in from the VCS menu.

While uploading on github, the new repository was made but there were no files inside it.
Please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have logged in (username/password) then try instead an https URL.

An SSH URL supposes PyCharm has access to a private/oublic key pair.
(and then uses an URL like `git@github.com:...`, not `Git@github.com`)